# Abrir popover (Bootstrap) ao clicar no checkbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

Possuo uma tabela, onde o usuário seleciona os meses que já foram realizadas as checagens. Para realizar essa checagem, basta o usuário marcar um `checkbox`. Porém, tenho uma nova demanda, que quando o usuário clicar no `checkbox`, aparece uma tela para o mesmo, para o usuário digitar a data da checagem.
Eu analisei alguns fóruns, e cheguei a conclusão que utilizar o [Popover (Bootstrap)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) realiza o que desejo.

Implemente um exemplo da utilização. Porém, ao selecionar o `checkbox`, ele traz o mesmo `popover` para todos os `checkbox`. Gostaria de uma forma de que cada `checkbox` possuísse o seu `popover`.

E além disso, neste exemplo o `popover` desaparece ao clicar no mesmo. Eu necessito que o mesmo fique na tela, para o usuário selecionar a data.

```js
$(function () {
    // create a single access point for your popover
    var $pop = $("#CheckBoxPopover");
    
    $('.checkBoxTips input').click(function (e) {
        setPopover(this);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
    $(document).click(function () {
        $pop.hide();
    });
    
    function setPopover(element) {
        setPopoverPosition(element);
        if ($(element).is(":checked")) {
            var title = $(element).attr("title");
            $pop.find("h3.popover-title").text(title);
            $pop.show();
        } else {
            var $checkedBoxes = $('.checkBoxTips input:checked')
            if ($checkedBoxes.length >0) {
                setPopover($checkedBoxes[0]);
            } else {
                $pop.hide();
            }
        }
    }
    
    function setPopoverPosition(element) {
        var offset = $(element).offset();
        $pop.css('left',offset.left + 20);
        $pop.css('top',offset.top - 25);
    }
});
```

```css
.checkBoxTips input {
    display: block;
}
#CheckBoxPopover {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
         -o-transition: all 1s ease;
            transition: all 1s ease;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="checkBoxTips"> 
<table style="width:1149px;" id="tblPrestacao" class="cell-border table-bordered tblCompleta table-responsive">
                <thead>
                    <tr bgcolor="#F1F1F1">
                        <th><p align="center">UF</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">Entidade</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">Tipo</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">1</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">2</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">3</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">4</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">5</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">6</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">7</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">8</th>
                        <th><p align="center">9</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">10</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">11</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">12</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">Responsável</p></th>
                        <th><p align="center">Observação</p></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
        <td style="width: 10px"><font size="2"> <b>GO</b></font></td>
        <td style="width: 250px">
            <font size="2">
                <a class="btnEditCliente" href="#" title="Editar Cliente">C&#226;mara de Castanhal</a>
            </font>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10px"><font size="2"> <b>A</b></font></td>
            <td bgcolor="gren"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="gren"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
        <td>User 1</td>
        <td>Sem Obs</td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
        <td style="width: 10px"><font size="2"> <b>ES</b></font></td>
        <td style="width: 250px">
            <font size="2">
                <a class="btnEditCliente" href="#" title="Editar Cliente">C&#226;mara de Brasília</a>
            </font>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10px"><font size="2"> <b>A</b></font></td>
            <td bgcolor="gren"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJaneiro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bJaneiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bJaneiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="gren"><font size="1"><b><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bFevereiro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bFevereiro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bFevereiro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMarco é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bMarco" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bMarco" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAbril é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bAbril" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bAbril" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bMaio é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bMaio" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bMaio" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJunho é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bJunho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bJunho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bJulho é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bJulho" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bJulho" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bAgosto é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bAgosto" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bAgosto" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bSetembro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bSetembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bSetembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bOutubro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bOutubro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bOutubro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bNovembro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bNovembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bNovembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
                    <td bgcolor="red"><font size="1"><b><input data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo bDezembro é obrigatório." name="[0].Mes.bDezembro" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].Mes.bDezembro" type="hidden" value="false" /></b></font></td>
        <td>User 1</td>
        <td>Sem Obs</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
     <div id='CheckBoxPopover' class="popover fade right in" style="display: hidden;">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Entre com a Data</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <input type="date"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Para os adeptos, segue [esse exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/37odd31x/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, @Randrade !

Uma solução seria você ter um `input[type="hidden"]` relacionado a cada `input[type="checkbox"]` e trabalhar com os [eventos que o Popover disponibiliza](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-events).

Neste caso, no momento que você selecionar um `input[type="checkbox"]`, o evento **show.bs.popover** será disparado e você poderá armazenar a referência entre os inputs e preencher a data. Ao fechar o popover, o evento **hide.bs.popover** será disparado e você poderá copiar para o `input[type="hidden"]` o valor do campo o qual foi informada a data.